# Into position or At or On

Tags: grammar

Is this correct to say "I'm into position" meaning that

1. You are ready to take some actions or like you are waiting one's permission to do something on someone's command
2. Or that you aggred with someone to come to some point to meet at

Comment: **into** is only used with movement.  You would say "I'm moving into position", and then "I'm in position", but not "I'm into position."  (Except in the slang sense of "I'm really into crime dramas", but that's a different meaning.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common way to express this in English is ***in* position**:

> I'm in position, ready for your signal.

This has a pretty strong association with the military (whether correct or not, it *sounds like* something soldiers would say, so you hear it in that context in movies and such). If you'd arranged to meet a friend you wouldn't say "in position," you would say "I'm here:"

> Where are you? I'm here in front of the Macy's at the mall.

Comment: and what about if friends waiting you to play online computer game and then you come saying i'm in position, or is it not okay too?

Comment: @Boyep no, I would say "I'm ready" or "I'm set up" or "I'm online." *If the game was a military game* (like Call of Duty or some such), then *when your in-game character* was waiting at some place you could say "I'm in position" referring to your in-game character. But I would not use it to refer to my physical body sitting at the computer.